# POST with if else

Tags: php, forms

I have a form that I am using to submit data to two separate end points. I am first sending the form data to a php script that processes the data. The script works in its basic configuration.

However I am having an issue changing the submitted content of a couple of fields in order to meet the end point requirements. I need to do this as each of the end points needs some of the data formatted differently.

For example .. I have a field that submits a '1' to the PHP script however I need to change the '1' to a 'Y'before passing it on.

I have attempted this change using the following code in the PHP script but I do not believe this is correct as I am not seeing the 'Y' submitted to the end point.

```
$pkng = $_POST['pkng'];
if ($pkng == "1") {
    $newpkng = 'Y';  
} else {
    $newpkng = '  ';
}
```

I appreciate this may be a simple question for many but I am still learning .. thanks in advance

Comment: `$_POST` is the **response** from a `POST` request; `pkng` has already been sent. You need to make the change **after** submitting the form, but **before** inserting to the database. Could you please add your code to show what happens once the form is submitted? Perhaps even the form itself if there's no additional logic? If this is the code before you send the variable on, then it looks fine; you simply need to ensure that `$POST_['pkng']` is indeed set correctly.

Comment: What do you get if you print (or `echo`) `$pkng`? Do you get a `1`?

Comment: when you say submitted to an 'end point' what exactly do you mean? Where and how do you try to pick up the value in $newpkng?